# How to add alias on self laravel eloquent ? Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

My query mysql like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM categories a
JOIN categories b ON b.parent_id = a.id
JOIN products c ON c.category_id = b.id
WHERE a.id = 1
```

I want change it to laravel eloquent

On the model category, I try like this :

```
self::join('categories b', 'b.parent_id', '=', 'a.id')
    ->join('products c', 'c.category_id', '=', 'b.id')
    ->findWhere(['a.id','=',$id]);
```

I'm confused add alias to `self`

How can I do it?

Note :

I want to use `self`. Not others

Comment: _**@Shadow**_: Did referred post really say anything about _**alias**_ for _**self**_ or anything else?

Comment: @Shadow, Seems this is no duplicate. My case is different. You should read my case slowly

Comment: @RavinderReddy well, both you and the OP should read the duplicate post slowly. It describes how to create a self join in laravel by setting up a relationship with itself. This is what you need to do here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're gonna do it in the model. I think you need to use `$this` instead of `self`. Just like what you did in the making of table relation :

```
return $this->hasMany('Blabla');
```